# Cypress capturing snack Bar

Tags: javascript, data-structures, devops, cypress, ui-automation

Generic code has been added to differntiate between the different Snackbar types in UI. Span has been added with data-test property created using key(mandatory) and variant(mandatory) with notification string e.g. ${key}-${variant}-notification i.e. xyz-error-notification. This span is wrapped around text and can be utilized for automation. So, it will be something like<span data-test= dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-notification>.
Categories of Snackbar has been added.

```
Error Snackbar  dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-error
Info Snackbar   dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-notification
Success Snackbar    dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-success
Warning Snackbar    dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-warning
```

I have to create a function in cypres automation where If a error snackbar will appear in UI then I have to fail to test case,if success snackbar will appear then I have to continue with the test case,else I have to capture info and warning snackbar  and also if anytype of snackbar will not be present from transition of one page to another then I have to log the message,no snackbar present.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated?

**From comments:**

So here is the flow:

- if (level === 'error') fail the test case
- if (level === 'success') check the remaining condition and continue with the test case
- if (level === 'warning') capture the warning message and log it
- if (level === 'info') capture the info message and log it
- if nothing is present log the message as "nothing is present"

Please help me with the exact code for this

Comment: Please keep in mind, questions on SO should be quite focused. You will get closed down if the question is too broad or not providing code that you have already tried. Perhaps you should flesh out a test and post it, along with more targeted question.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking a question. You should at least attempt to write an initial test and post that code here, along with any errors you are getting and the HTML you are trying to test.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this, testing for span with jQuery

```js
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  const $span = $body.find(`span[data-test^="${key}-${variant}-"]`)
  if ($span.length === 0) {
    cy.log('Nothing found')
    return
  }
  if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'error') {
    throw 'error'
  }
  if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'success') {
    return  
  }
  cy.log($span.attr('data-test'))
})
```

If you want to capture the transitory element that may or may not appear, use a recursive function

```js
function eatSnack(level = 0) {

  // Figure out how many times you want to check before giving up
  if (level === 10) {
    cy.log('Nothing found')
    return
  }

  cy.get('body').then($body => {
    const $span = $body.find(`span[data-test^="${key}-${variant}-"]`)

    if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'error') {
      throw 'error'
    }
    if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'success') {
      return  
    }
    if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'warning') {
      cy.log($span.attr('data-test'))
      return
    }
    if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'info') {
      cy.log($span.attr('data-test'))
      return
    }

    cy.wait(10)        // adjust this to suit SnackBar
    eatSnack(++level)  // try again
  }
})

eatSnack()  // start looking
```

Comment: In the same way for warning and info
 if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'warning') {
    log the warning message is present
  }
 and  if ($span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3] === 'info') {
    log the info message is present
  }

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks Mihi. Success u have mentioned 2 times, I have to also verify dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-notification and dataTest ? dataTest : ${key}-${variant}-warning snackbar.It mesna notification and warning snackbar

Comment: You got it now!

Comment: so just asking dont I have to explicitly give the condition for warning and notiification

Comment: No guarantee on that recursive function, you have to adjust wait time and maximum level to suit that Snackbar showing and hiding.

Comment: I am getting an error as key and variant is not defined

Comment: Also for split method its giving error as cannot read property split of undefined

Comment: key and variant are the same as in your question. Where do you get them from?

Comment: This is probably too advanced, you need a certain level of javascript knowledge.

Comment: Mihi i didnt get u

Comment: key and variant is the additional data test defined by developers. Let me know any other details if u need

Comment: for eg here is one data test data-test="***_****_****_error-error-notification"

Comment: Can we use switch and case statement here

Comment: @Mihi you would need to test that the find succeeded before getting the attribute.

Comment: @Electron do u have the updated code for the same

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't mind seeing more context, but from what you've given

```js
const key = 'abc'
const variant = '123'
cy.get(`span[data-test^="${key}-${variant}-"]`)   // queries starting portion of attr
  .then($span => {
    const level = $span.attr('data-test').split('-')[3]  // what type is it?
    if (level === 'error') throw "Woops an error" // fail the test
    if (level === 'success') return // do nothing
    
    // otherwise log something
    cy.log($span.attr('data-test'))
```

Since snackbars are generally transitory, you would have to carefully place the code after the trigger action.

Comment: I have to call  this function in my main test code after each transition. I have to call this function six times in my test code

Comment: can u make the code more ellaborative for the action after error,success,info and warning

Comment: LOL I was going to ask you that - all I can discern is that you want to do something different for each level, so I gave you the test code to differentiate.

Comment: I can say, if you want to fail the test just throw an error `throw "Something went wrong"` or whatever message takes your fancy.

Comment: so here is the flow:
if (level === 'error')
fail the test case
if (level === 'success')
check the reamining condition and continue with the test case
if (level === 'warning')
capture the warning message and log it
if (level === 'info')
capture the info message and log it
if nothing is present log the message as nothing is present.

Please help me with the exact code for this

Comment: I've updated your question. The only thing I can't figure is how to detect nothing is present. `cy.get(span[data-test^="${key}-${variant}-"]).should('not.exist')` will fail the whole test if there's a span with another level.

Comment: so whats ur suggestion here,I mean how will I handle the transition if no snackbar is present

Comment: You will probably be stymied by that one. You can use jQuery to see if an element is present, but you are trying to catch a transitory element (did I mention that?) So when you check for it, is it before, during or after the Snackbar has shown itself (or not shown itself as the case may be)?

Comment: I am getting an error as key is not defined.